# How to interpet the bolded lines in bayesopt

Tags: optimization, hyperparameter-tuning, bayesian

I am using bayesopt to maximize a function that is everywhere less or equal to zero $(f(x) \leq 0)$. The score is essentially a negated Mean Absolute Error because the default behavior of bayesopt is maximization.

I have always interpreted the bold outputs of bayesopt as the current best (is that correct?). However, this is the first time that I see erratic behavior in the bolded parts, as they seem to randomly pick highly negative numbers (e.g. -7.16e+05) and completely misses the highest value  (-1.129e+0). This can be seen in the following picture:

[image: bayesopt results]

So, is this a bug or am I not interpeting correctly the meaning of the bolded lines?